# crypto: how to generate ECDH PEM?

Tags: node.js

Do I assume correctly that a Node.js generated ECDH key, can be formatted to PEM by just wrapping the base64 encoded buffer in headers and footers?

```
const { ECDH } = require('crypto')
const ecdh = ECDH('secp256k1')
ecdh.generateKeys()

const publicKey = ecdh.getPublicKey('buffer', 'uncompressed')
const privateKey = ecdh.getPrivateKey('buffer', 'uncompressed')

const publicPem = `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n${publicKey.toString('base64')}\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n`
const privatePem = `-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n${privateKey.toString('base64')}\n-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----\n`
console.log('==================================')
console.log(privatePem)
console.log(publicPem)
console.log('==================================')
```

Comment: did you assume correctly?